# Solr.NET and Chinese characters

Tags: unicode, solr, cjk, solrnet

I have a search index that handles both English and Chinese content. All documents are imported to SOLR by Solr.NET

When I search the Chinese content from the browser (localhost:8389/solr/...) everything works fine, but when I execute the search using Solr.NET then I get 0 hit :(

I tried to set up a [logger](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LoggingInDefaultJettySetup) to see what's the difference between browser search and Solr.NET search but I get question marks (??????) instead of Chinese characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: does this SOLR net has encodding settings somewhere? (u probably want utf8)

Comment: Haven't found any settings. The thing is, Solr.NET indexed all Chinese documents w/o problems, it can read the Chinese fields, but cannot create a proper query :(

Comment: If you get question marks it means that your client has the encoding set wrong. Where exactly do you see the ? marks?

Comment: Solr has created a file called `solr0.log`. I opened that file with Notepad++ and changed encoding.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/MAO17Dmrpzk/OVZEvTmzgjMJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open solr0.log with your browser instead of Notepad++ in order to make sure that this is a real problem and to find out which encoding the file was saved as - if it's not Unicode, chances are that Solr.NET can't search it.

Notepad++ has been known to have trouble with Chinese, either because of the encoding (Notepad++ doesn't support typical Chinese encodings like gb or big5) or because of the default font, which may or may not support Chinese characters. Browsers are more forgiving and will do anything in order to display the file correctly. In fact, to convert non-unicode Asian encodings to unicode, I often open a file in my browser, which will detect the correct encoding and display the raw contents, and then CTRL+A CTRL+C CTRL+V everything into Editor, save as UTF-8, done.

Comment: I couldn't read the Chinese characters in browser as well :(
Anyway, the problem was in my queries and not in Solr.net. Thanks for the help.